# Laravel 4 Input::get() changes encoding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an application using Laravel 4. In my signup form, I have a "country" and a "state" field which I would want to autocomplete using ajax.

I have no problem retrieving the data from the server, but I have a small problem that seems to come from the `Input::get()` method - or one of its parents. If I input "Québec" in the state field, when I use `Input::get()`, the accent get encoded. If I look in the $_POST super-global, the value is "Québec", but from `Input::get()`, the value is "Qu�bec".

I know I could just use the $_POST super-global directly, but I want to work with the methods of Laravel.

Do any of you know how I can fix this/what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out I wasted a week on this, I the problem doesn't even come from the `Input::get()` method. It came from the `strtolower()` I use after I retrieve the value. The data is encoded in UTF-8 and I have to use `mb_strtolower()` instead to support it.

Comment: You can also use `Str::lower($string)`.